# Is there a programmatic way to check if brightness is at max or min value on OSX?

Tags: macos, applescript

So, I am making a virtual assistant that responds to voice commands and replies back when the command has been executed. I am currently working on a script to increase/decrease brightness, and reply with `say "brightness increased"` or `say "brightness decreased"`

I want to set a condition that will check brightness level, and if the value is at max or min, reply saying that the brightness is at max/min value ... is there any way to check brightness level with AppleScript? I have been searching the web for hours now and I have yet to turn up any useful information on this... here is the code I have so far, with some pseudocode included for where I want to implement checking for min/max values, because at this point I'm pretty much stumped...

```
on run argv
    if (brightnessLevel = max) then              -- start of pseudocode
        say "brightness is already at max level"
        error number -128
    else if (brightnessLevel = min) then
        say "brightness is already at min level"
        error number -128                        -- end of pseudocode
    if (count of argv = 1) then
        if (item 1 of argv as string = "up") then
            tell application "System Events"
                key code 144
                say "brightness increased" using "Trinoids"
            end tell
        else if (item 1 of argv as string = "down") then
            tell application "System Events"
                key code 145
                say "brightness decreased" using "Trinoids"
            end tell
        end if
    else
        return "Error: argument count invalid"
    end if
end run
```

**Edit:** I figured I should specify, I do not want to use the `brightness` package from homebrew, because if there's a way to do this without dependencies, that's the way I want to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works on my MacBook Pro:

```
set backlightLevel to do shell script "nvram backlight-level | awk '{print $2}'"

if backlightLevel is "%ff%03" then
    say "brightness is already at max level"
    return
else if backlightLevel is "%00%00" then
    say "brightness is already at min level"
    return
end if
```

Comment: Sorry I took so long to reply, I had a strict deadline to meet. I just thought I would clarify that your solution did work, however the values it printed out were different than the ones you provided in your post -- no matter though, it was just a matter of setting min and max brightness and copying the values they print out to the terminal. Thanks for the solution!

Comment: However, if I was wanting to make a solution that would work across all mac computers, this solution wouldn't work, I think I know a workaround to make it work across all macs, but to do that I would need to know if there's a way for a script to know if it's a macbook or an imac, because the keys codes for brightness up and brightness down are different between the macbook and imac. Would you happen to know if there's a way to know if the user is using a macbook or an imac? Is there any way to grep the type of display? That would be enough information to make this possible for me.

Comment: @Elliot Tregoning, This will get the model name: `set modelName to do shell script "system_profiler SPHardwareDataType | awk -F ': ' '/Model Name:/{print $2}'"`

Comment: @Elliot Tregoning, This will get you the display name: `tell application "System Events" to set displayName to display name of current desktop`

Comment: @Elliot Tregoning, This too will get you the display name:`set displayName to do shell script "system_profiler SPDisplaysDataType | awk '/^[ ]+Displays:/{getline; sub(/^[ ]+/, \"\"); print $0;}'"` Although this assume only one Display.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution using AppleScript only.

This works for me using the latest version of Sierra on MacBook Pro 15”

```
property theBrightness : ""

tell application "System Preferences"
    reveal anchor "displaysDisplayTab" of pane "com.apple.preference.displays"
    tell application "System Events" to tell process "System Preferences" to tell window 1
        set theBrightness to get value of value indicator 1 of slider 1 of group 2 of tab group 1
        set theBrightness to result * 10
        set theBrightness to round theBrightness
        set theBrightness to theBrightness / 10
        say "Brightness Is Currently At Level " & (theBrightness * 10 as integer) using "Trinoids"
        if theBrightness is equal to 1 then
            say "Brightness Is Already At Maximum Level" using "Trinoids"
        end if
        if theBrightness is equal to 0.1 then
            say "Brightness Is Already At Minimum Level" using "Trinoids"
        end if
    end tell

    --  call following the handler anywhere in this script as long as it's before the "quit" command
    my setBrightnessLevel(0.5) -- lowest to highest values from 0.1 to 1.0  example: .5 = halfway bright

    quit
end tell

on setBrightnessLevel(theNumber)
    tell application "System Events" to tell process "System Preferences" to tell window 1 to ¬
        set value of value indicator 1 of slider 1 of group 2 of tab group 1 to theNumber
end setBrightnessLevel
```

---

Here is a version using the 16 values for the keyboard increments.  Still working on polishing it up at the moment

```
global roundedUpLevelValues
global theDesiredBrightness

property theBrightness : ""
property levelValues : {0.062499992549, 0.125000014901, 0.187499955297, 0.250000029802, 0.312499970198, 0.374999910593, 0.437500119209, 0.500000059605, 0.562500238419, 0.624999880791, 0.687500119209, 0.749999761581, 0.8125, 0.875000238419, 0.937499880791, 1.0}
property dontRoundtheDesiredBrightness : 0.0625

set dialogBrightnessLevel to display dialog "Darkest To Brightest... Insert A Value From 1 to 16" default answer "16" buttons {" Cancel", "Set Brightness"} default button 2
set theDesiredBrightness to text returned of dialogBrightnessLevel -- darkest to brightest... Insert a value from 1 to 16

set roundedUpLevelValues to (item theDesiredBrightness of levelValues) * 100000
set roundedUpLevelValues to round roundedUpLevelValues
set roundedUpLevelValues to roundedUpLevelValues / 100000

tell application "System Preferences"
    reveal anchor "displaysDisplayTab" of pane "com.apple.preference.displays"
    tell application "System Events" to tell process "System Preferences" to tell window 1
        set theBrightness to get value of value indicator 1 of slider 1 of group 2 of tab group 1
        set theBrightness to result * 16
        set theBrightness to round theBrightness
        set theBrightness to theBrightness / 16
        say "Brightness Is Currently At Level " & (theBrightness * 16 as integer) using "Trinoids"
        if theBrightness is equal to item 16 of levelValues then
            say "Brightness Is Already At Maximum Level" using "Trinoids"
        end if
        if theBrightness is equal to dontRoundtheDesiredBrightness then
            say "Brightness Is Already At Minimum Level" using "Trinoids"
        end if
    end tell
    --  call the following  handler anywhere in this script as long as it's before the "quit" command
    try
        my setBrightnessLevel(roundedUpLevelValues)
    end try
    quit
end tell

on setBrightnessLevel(theDesiredBrightness)
    tell application "System Events" to tell process "System Preferences" to tell window 1 to ¬
        set value of value indicator 1 of slider 1 of group 2 of tab group 1 to theDesiredBrightness
end setBrightnessLevel
```

Comment: FWIW Instead of using the actual `name` of the `window`, i.e. `window "Built-in Retina Display"`, just use e.g. `window 1`, as it's always better to tokenize objects unless the use case absolutely requires the actual `name` _property_ of the _object_ being _referenced_. Also what's with "Here is another solution using AppleScript only." `do shell script` is AppleScript! :)

Comment: That said, I had actually already written an "AppleScript only" using the _value_ of `value indicator 1 of slider 1` and didn't post it as I ran out of time at the time and hadn't got back to it yet, however I must say that I like your approach better in respect to what I didn't post, although there are actually 16 different levels, not 10 when using the brightness function keys. Is there a way to do it using the actual number of steps the brightness function keys can take?  Also on my MacBook Pro valid values of `value indicator 1 of slider 1` are `0.0` thru `1.0` at `0.0625` increments.

Comment: Kudos on the "window 1" approach. As to "Also what's with "Here is another solution using AppleScript only." do shell script is AppleScript! " ... Yes although it is all AppleScript it's still calls a shell script command...  Speaking for myself only, I am a shell script Moron lol And I get sidetracked very easily.  That said, I spent nearly 2 hours doing research in Terminal scrutinizing and reading man pages because of you lol.  I will also look into the 16 step increment you mentioned To see what I can come up with

Comment: Wow, I much prefer to use the KISS method to make the list! To make an AppleScript list that's formatted from `0` to `1` in `0.0625` increments, in Terminal I'd use: `seq 0 0.0625 1 | tr '\n' ',' | sed -e 's/,/, /g' -e 's/^/\{/' -e 's/, $/\}\n/'` which produces: `{0, 0.0625, 0.125, 0.1875, 0.25, 0.3125, 0.375, 0.4375, 0.5, 0.5625, 0.625, 0.6875, 0.75, 0.8125, 0.875, 0.9375, 1}` and copy and paste the result into the AppleScript script.

Comment: I definitely would have automated that task had the values returned of the “value of” command given me nice pretty numbers like 0.0625..  But instead I got numbers like… 0.062499992549.  I figured I may as well just get the actual real values of the numbers first, then modify the script with the rounding commands

Comment: I owe you an apology, when I said "there are actually 16 different levels, not 10 when using the brightness function keys." in a previous comment... I misspoke and should have said... there are actually 17 different levels of brightness, which is implemented in 16 steps from `0.0` to `1.0` in `0.0625` increments, not 10 when using the brightness function keys. So because of my mistake I've cause you to write code that doesn't truly reflect the actual facts, however I did say in that same comment "`value indicator 1 of slider 1` are `0.0` thru `1.0` at `0.0625` increments".

Comment: I'm sorry I misspoke and you didn't see the discrepancy which may have caused an exercise in futility.